# My own page number from file {counters}

Tags: page-numbering, counters

I would like to add my own page number in my publications.

I have file: `numerki.tex`

```
zzzero
jEden
dWa
trZy
cztery
...
dwadzIescia
etc......
```

How I can add counter `\counter\cyferki` from file. each line is next counter

```
0=zzzero
1=jEden
2=dWa .....
```

(numbers are in utf-8 and different capitalic)

And next put it to page number in my specific font.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24657

Comment: No, because next value are not romanic, string, arabic etc. it is a randomly text and mathematical formula. Each line is a small TeX code with different font and color

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 5):

[image]

pages.txt:

```
One
Two (2)
3
FFFFOOOOUUUURRRR
five gold rings
```

document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\advance\textheight-20\baselineskip
\advance\paperheight-20\baselineskip
\pdfpageheight\paperheight


\makeatletter

%%%%%
% filler text
\def\txt#1#2{%
\count@#1\relax
\@tempcnta#2\relax
\@txt}
\def\@txt{%
\let\MessageBreak\space\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont
\ifnum\numexpr(\count@/7)*7=\count@\@eha\space \@ehb\space\fi
\ifnum\numexpr(\count@/5)*5=\count@\@eha\space \@ehc\space\fi
\ifodd\count@ Red yellow blue green balck white. \fi
\ifnum\numexpr(\count@/9)*9=\count@ One two three four five. \fi
\advance\count@\@ne
\ifnum\@tempcnta>\count@
\expandafter\@txt
\fi
}

%%%%%%%%%%%

\newread\pagenofile
\openin\pagenofile=pages.txt
\count@\z@
\loop
\advance\count@\@ne
\ifeof\pagenofile
\else
\read\pagenofile to \tmp
\expandafter\let\csname page=\the\count@\endcsname\tmp
%%%debugging\expandafter\show\csname page=\the\count@\endcsname
\repeat

\renewcommand\thepage{\csname page=\arabic{page}\endcsname}

\begin{document}

\txt{1}{100}



\end{document}
```

Comment: @jak are your numbers in pages.txt in the current directory?

Comment: @jak oh I left in a `\show`  debugging line (I have those so often I didn't think to remove it:-) I have updated the code with that line commented out. The above is the whole code!

Comment: Please download code. https://github.com/jak00/test-counter-how is @
David Carlisle https://github.com/jak00/test-counter-line is @
Steven B. Segl any not working

Comment: Your code on github works but it is in utf8 so you have to add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` to the tex file and the last number in the file  would make any text following the page number bold change `\bf{five}` to `\textbf{five}` as `\bf` does not take an argument (and is not even defined by default in latex)

Comment: @jak I forgot to ping you, please see comment above

Comment: Yes, I change github https://github.com/jak00/test-counter-how it working fine.

Comment: Your code don't work in xelatex ;-(    this is problem, I dont know what i can install ttf or otf font in pdflatex

Comment: @jak It should work (if you don't use inputenc) I'll test it and see

Comment: @jak Your file works fine in xelatex, but xelatex is utf8 already so you don't need (and can't use) inputenc

Comment: ok, i change my font and working in pdflatex. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For this numerki.tex file:

```
$x^2=\ln y$
zzzero
jEden
dWa
trZy
cztery
...
dwadzIescia
etc......
```

it works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand\thepage{\csname arg\roman{page}\endcsname}

\begin{document}
\readdef{numerki.tex}{\mypagenum}
\getargsC{\mypagenum}

\section{Test chapter one}
\lipsum[1-8]
\section{Test chapter two}
\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

Confirmed it works for math mode in pages, since user mentioned that.

[image]

This alternate version below, while a bit longer in code, will allow the use of regular spaces in your input lines without requiring you to change them to hardspaces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{readarray}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\readdef[2]{%
\def\first@row{T}%
\def\first@plane{T}%
\catcode\endlinechar=10\relax%
\def#2{}%
\newread\file%
\openin\file=#1%
\loop\unless\ifeof\file%
    \read\file to\fileline % Reads a line of the file into \fileline%
    \protected@edef#2{#2\fileline}%
    \if T\first@row\getargsC{#2}\setcounter{@col}{\numexpr(\narg-1)}%
      \edef\ncols{\arabic{@col}}\def\first@row{F}\setcounter{@row}{1}%
    \else%
      \if T\first@plane\getargsC{\fileline}\ifthenelse{\equal{\narg}{1}}{%
        \edef\nrows{\arabic{@row}}\def\first@plane{F}}{%
        \addtocounter{@row}{1}}%
      \fi
    \fi%
    \expandafter\protected@edef\csname record\roman{@row}\endcsname{%
      \fileline}%
\repeat%
\closein\file%
\catcode\endlinechar=5\relax%
}
\makeatother

\renewcommand\thepage{\csname record\roman{page}\endcsname}

\begin{document}
\readdef{numerki.tex}{\mypagenum}

\section{Test chapter one}
\lipsum[1-8]
\section{Test chapter two}
\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hm.... You answer not working on my TeX 

I have https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5413128 file name pages.txt each line is code in TeX. 

In Your Ansver i get  

LaTeX Error: File `readarray.sty' not found. 
&
! Undefined control sequence.
l.8 \readdef
            {numerki.tex}{\mypagenum}

Comment: @jak The `\getargsC` command grabs words, not lines. Thus, if you wish to have spaces in your page numbers, use hardspaces (~). And if you use a math formula, there can be no softspaces in it, or `\getargsC` will break the formula into multiple words (which for math mode, does not work out well).

Comment: readarray.sty is necesary? I havent this style. please send me Your code to e-mail or pastebin.

Comment: @jak  Can be downloaded at http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/readarray

Comment: Yout code working. Many thanks https://github.com/jak00/test-counter-how

Comment: @jak See edited answer.  If changing spaces to hardspaces is too inconvenient, I provide alternative version that, while longer, digests blankspaces directly.