# Custom page numbering

Tags: page-numbering

So after looking around on the web and finding nothing, i'm asking it here:

How can I convert pagination to a "Chapter-section" (see image below) style rather than numerically advancing page numbers.

PS: I've also been looking for a tutorial to edit all the features of the ToC (and page design in general)

[image: ToC from "Feynman's lectures on physics"]

Comment: I am currently using the memoir document class, and haven't tried anything anything for this particular problem, as i couldn't find any documentation on this aspect.

Comment: The problem is, a google search on this matter indicates how i can change page numbering from arabic to roman or alphabetical, but there is no documentation for deeper customization.

Comment: What about unnumbered chapters? please give us a minimal example of the whole structure of your document

Comment: there is no problem with memoir, but at least for me there is a problem with unnumbered chapters, do you have `\chapter*{....}` like command in your document? index? bibliography?

Comment: you can see this http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24657/how-to-do-custom-page-numbering,  this is  duplicate, but since you are new user  ?

Comment: @touhami this concerns numbering for different parts of the document, my question is about the whole page nulbering system, to not display an advancing number for each page.

Comment: @touhami i don't have unnumbered chapters, the expected behaviour would be to not have any nulbering on the bottom of the page, or switch to natural page nulbering in this case.

Comment: Very strange! What is the purpose to have the chapter number in front of the page number if it is already in the left part of the contents?

Comment: it is a very effective way of looking up a page in a large book, the image in the question which uses this is "Feynman's lectures on physics", the helpfulness is not for the contents page but rather for the page numbering inside the actual book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for example

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic} % you don't need this
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{page}{chapter}
\renewcommand\thepage{\ifnum \c@chapter>\z@ \thechapter-\fi \@arabic\c@page}
\let\oldafterchaptertitle\afterchaptertitle
\renewcommand{\afterchaptertitle}{\oldafterchaptertitle\refstepcounter{page}}
\makeatother

\chapter{First}
\section{Foo}
\lipsum[1-20]

\chapter{Last}
\section{Bar}
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

Here is a solution (a similar solution [How to do custom page numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24657/how-to-do-custom-page-numbering))

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for example

\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{\refstepcounter{chapter}}{\refstepcounter{chapter}\refstepcounter{page}}%
{}{\errmessage{problem in patching \noexpand\chapter}}
\@addtoreset{page}{chapter}
\renewcommand\thepage{\ifnum \c@chapter>\z@ \thechapter-\fi \@arabic\c@page}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents


\chapter{First}
\section{Foo}
\lipsum[1-20]

\chapter{Last}
\section{Bar}
\lipsum[1-20]

% here you can see the problem, one can try \setcounter{chapter}{0} if all unnumbered chapter are at the end

\chapter*{Last}
\section{Bar}
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that seems to be the solution, the problem is I don't understand the code, any documentation to get me going?

Comment: I will need to understand the code for starters because : your code compiles but when i copy paste in my preamble (or structure.tex) i get error messages :  **LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}. [\@addtoreset{page}**  and **problem in patching \chapter . [...ge{problem in patching \noexpand\chapter}}]**

Comment: we need a minimal example of your code

Comment: here's  my main.tex, the chapters I include are only chapters sections and paragraphs: http://pastebin.com/ZJREX1vK

Comment: also here's my structure.tex : http://pastebin.com/xdy65HnQ

Comment: @JackHalford answer updated

Comment: This works now, I still want to understand your code, please link useful documentation on this (pretty much every command you used) or generally a guide on customising a latex document.